# How to avoid reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function in datagridview end edit event in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` with `datasource` of a `datatable`,
when the user change the value of it(in cell of `datagridview`), `cellendedit` update the data to `database` and after that new data from `database` set to that datatable and load in `datagridview`.

when I end edit of cell by pressing enter button everything is Ok, but when I want to end edit by leaving the focus from cell this exception occurred:

> Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.

with this code I make the error goes away:

```
private void RationFormulationdgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (!RationFormulationdgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected)
    {
        return;
    } 

    RationFormulationDBConnection.UpdateFeedsDetails(this);
    RationFormulationDBConnection.SetFeedsIntoRationdormulationdgv(this);
}
```

But the problem is edit is not applied when losing focus.

how should I fix this?

Comment: have you done a google search on the exact error..?

Comment: yes, I don't have any problem when pressing enter, when leaving focus this error happen

Comment: well put breakpoints in your code and start using the debugger.. how are we supposed to know what you are doing when we don't see your code..?

Comment: @MethodMan Honestly I'm a Beginner, I think this error have s simple solution, I do what you said tanks

Comment: please do not use thinks like `I'm a beginner` If you can find your way to Stackoverflow, you can surely find your way to `Google` to do a simple search please do that in the future before posting here

Comment: @MethodMan Ok, forgive me for making you mad, I did the search first but I could't find a solution that's why I asked the question, But as you say I search more, tanks anyway

Comment: I am not mad I am just giving you some good advice / pointers

Comment: @MethodMan Hi again, I edited my question, any help would be appreciated .

Comment: on this line `RationFormulationdgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected` shouldn't be .Value vs .Selected

Comment: @MethodMan        `If (RationFormulationdgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex])`
I write it like this but it says:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' to 'bool'

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is .. you cannot convert an Integer which is `the Index to a bool`

Comment: @MethodMan well can you help me what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve my problem by moving coeds from `CellEndEdit` event to `Cellvaluechanged` event and it seems ok and coeds runs without any problem